# Cold fusion and template paths

Tags: coldfusion

I work in a live environment and that can not be changed.

I am attempting to set up a ad-hoc dev environment so that I am not forced to changes so many paths just to test code.

Currently the main page calls a ton of other cfm pages using the cfincude template tag.

I have moved the pages to a seperate folder for clean up.

In my attempt to create a dev environment. I have created a cfm page that just sets the path to the templates.

includes.cfm

`<!--set for dev contactinformation page-->
<cfset CIP = "include/dev/mh/MarContactInformationIncUpdate.cfm">`

here is the main page where I call the includes.cfm page

```
        <cfset ContactMainPage = "MarMgt.cfm">
<cfparam name="CIP" default="MarContactInformationInc.cfm">
<cfif LocalAdmin neq 1>
    <!--- If not an admin don't let the user use these variables --->
    <cfset CIP = "MarContactInformationInc.cfm">
</cfif>

<cfif localuserid eq 1868>

    <!--- <cfinclude template="include/dev/mh/includes.cfm"> --->

</cfif>


<cfsavecontent variable="MainContent">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <cfinclude template= "include/mar/headerMenu.cfm">
        <cfif IsDefined("message")>
            <tr>
                <td  align="center" class="AlertMessage"><cfoutput>#message#</cfoutput></td>
            </tr>
        </cfif>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <!--- Information Page Sections --->

            <!--- Displays callbacks that have time in which they need to take care of. --->
            <cfinclude template="include/mar/CallTimeAlert.cfm">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    </cfif>
```

It is currently commented out to get the page to display while I work on a few other things.  However whenever I un-comment the line

```
<!--- <cfinclude template="include/dev/mh/includes.cfm"> --->
```

It then errors stating that it can not find the template

```
<cfinclude template="include/mar/CallTimeAlert.cfm">
```

I know the paths are correct.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there appears to be repeated code.

Comment: you're using relative paths when identifying your template. make sure that's correct based on the file you're calling it from.

Comment: the paths are correct.  I can navigate to them even when I get the error.  Plus in the above code it works because the includes.cfm page is comments out.  If I un-comment it will error stating that it can not find the calltimealert.cfm file.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out [#GetCurrentTemplatePath()#](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cf9.html) just before the call to `CallTimeAlert.cfm` to make sure you are where you think you are? (since you're using relative paths)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was due to the relative paths.

While I was correctly referencing all paths, paths that were set within a page that was included had incorrect paths.

My work around was to declare a path in the application.cfc.

Thanks for all the help.